# C# How kill process to Remote machine?

Tags: c#

How can i kill process to remote machine without using taskkill in c#?
I saved the machine name in a text box.

Thanks all for replies!

Comment: Have you tried PsTools?

Comment: I thought it, but I wanted to know if it was possible to use a feature already in c#, without use the windows tools.